How to write VBA to do INDEX and MATCH based on available rows instead of the whole column?
Sub ApplyFormulas()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim newCol As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

newCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
ws.Cells(1, newCol).Value = "Formula"

ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, newCol), ws.Cells(lastRow, newCol)).Formula2 = "=INDEX(Sheet2!E:E, MATCH(1, (Sheet2!A:A=Sheet1!A2)*(Sheet2!C:C=Sheet1!C2), 0))" 

How to change the formula from
=INDEX(Sheet2!E:E,

to
=INDEX(Sheet2!$E$2:$E$54483

where the search array is fixed and based on the available rows in Sheet2 since I'm going to use the same macro for different files

Append Lookup Formula Column

The Calling Procedure (Usage)
Sub AppendLookupFormulaColumnCALL()
    AppendLookupFormulaColumn ThisWorkbook, _
        "Sheet2", Array("A", "C"), "E", _
        "Sheet1", Array("A", "C"), "Formula"
End Sub

The Called Procedure (A Helper Method)
Sub AppendLookupFormulaColumn( _
        wb As Workbook, _
        SourceSheetName As String, _
        SourceLookupColumns As Variant, _
        SourceReturnColumn As String, _
        TargetSheetName As String, _
        TargetLookupColumns As Variant, _
        TargetColumnTitle As String)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SourceSheetName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim sdrg As Range: Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets(TargetSheetName)
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = tws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim tdrg As Range: Set tdrg = trg.Resize(trg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        
    Dim LookupArrayString As String, c As Long
    
    For c = LBound(SourceLookupColumns) To UBound(SourceLookupColumns)
        LookupArrayString = LookupArrayString & "*" & "('" _
            & SourceSheetName & "'!" & sdrg.Columns(SourceLookupColumns(c)) _
            .Address & "=" & tdrg.Rows(1).Columns(TargetLookupColumns(c)) _
            .Address(0, 0) & ")"
    Next c
    
    Dim FormulaString As String: FormulaString = "=INDEX('" _
        & SourceSheetName & "'!" & sdrg.Columns(SourceReturnColumn).Address _
        & ",MATCH(1," & Right(LookupArrayString, Len(LookupArrayString) - 1) _
        & ",0))"
    
    trg.Cells(1).Offset(, trg.Columns.Count).Value = TargetColumnTitle
    tdrg.Columns(1).Offset(, trg.Columns.Count).Formula2 = FormulaString

End Sub



The approach is similar to how you would get the last row number in column A of Sheet1.

    Dim lastRowE As Long, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastRowE = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, newCol), ws.Cells(lastRow, newCol)).Formula2 = "=INDEX(Sheet2!E2:E" & lastRowE & ", MATCH(1, (Sheet2!A2:A" & lastRowE & "=Sheet1!A2)*(Sheet2!C2:C" & lastRowE & "=Sheet1!C2), 0))"

